# Showing that $V \unlhd S_4$, so that $S_4$ is not simple.

Tags: finite-groups, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $V = \{id, (12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$. I am trying to show that $V \unlhd S_4$, so that $S_4$ is not simple.

As I understand it, to show that $V \unlhd S_4$ $-$ i.e. that $V$ is a normal subgroup of $S_4$ $-$ I need to show that $\forall x, \forall y \in V (xy^{-1} \in V)$ and that $\forall s \in S_4$, ( $sVs^{-1} = V)$.

Is this correct? If so, how many checks do I need to make?

Comment: Naively, a whole bunch. But at least for normality, if you know anything about what conjugation does to cycle structure, you can basically just appeal to that.

Comment: Your set $V$ has $5$ elements, which cannot be a subgroup of $S_4$ which has $24$ elements. You can show $S_4$ is not simple since $A_4$ is a normal subgroup. If instead you're trying to $A_4$ is not a simple group, it may be easier to appeal to the Sylow theorems (specifically the third one) if you know them.

Comment: Apologies everyone, I have  adjusted the question.

Answer (score 1):

let $S_4$ act on the variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ by permutation of suffixes in the obvious way.

now define the three expressions:
$$
A =(x_1x_2-x_3x_4)^2 \\
B =(x_1x_3-x_2x_4)^2 \\
C =(x_1x_4-x_2x_3)^2
$$
given any $\sigma \in S_4$ the action just defined induces a permutation of $A,B$ and $C$.

can you (a) check that this construction gives a homomorphism $S_4 \to S_3$. 
(b) show that the kernel of this homomorphism is your group $V$?

if so, then you have shown that $V \triangleleft S_4$

Comment: You could also use $x_1x_2+x_3x_4$, etc, and avoid squaring. This construction is related to the resolvent cubic associated to a degree four polynomial, where one takes $f$ with roots $r_1,\ldots,r_4$ and defines the cubic with roots $r_1r_2+r_3r_4$, etc. This allows to obtain the Galois group of $f$ by looking at that of $g$.

Comment: thanks for that insight, Pedro

Comment: Can you explain each part a bit more? I'm still new to group theory. Are you saying that each of the variables $x_i$ are the elements of $V$ or are they something else? Also, what do you mean by $(x_1x_2 - x_3x_4)^2$? For the case of $A$, am I just considering the cycle $(x_1x_2x_3^{-1}x_4)(x_1x_2x_3^{-1}x_4)$? If not, what is the meaning of $-x_3$?

Comment: the framework is a group acting on a set. you could think of the $x_i$ as generators for an algebraic structure, e.g. a commutative polynomial ring such as $\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since all elements in $V$ are involutions, it's easy to check $V$ is a subgroup. Note that any conjugation will not change the order of an element. If $\exists s,v$ such that $svs^{-1}\notin V$, $svs^{-1}$ must be of the form $(i\ j)$. Then by symmetry, all elements of form $(i\ j)$ will be in the conjugacy class containing $V$. So the conjugacy class containing $V$ will consist of $6+3+1=10$ elements, which doesn't divide $|S_4|=24$. Contradiction.

P.S. To show that $A_4$ is normal is much easier.