# About normality of $V = \{1,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ in $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am trying to follow the argument in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1490151/360858). Quoting:

> Since all elements in $V$ are involutions, it's easy to check $V$ is a subgroup. Note that any conjugation will not change the order of an element. If $\exists s,v$ such that $svs^{-1}\notin V$, $svs^{-1}$ must be of the form $(i\ j)$. Then by symmetry, all elements of form $(i\ j)$ will be in the conjugacy class containing $V$. So the conjugacy class containing $V$ will consist of $6+3+1=10$ elements, which doesn't divide $|S_4|=24$. Contradiction.

What I don't see is why "by symmetry, all elements of form $(ij)$ will be in the conjugacy class of $V$". How to see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "symmetry" is just an application of the following  general fact:

> two permutations in $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cyclic structure.

The proof of the normality of $V$ in $S_4$ can be made shorter by observing that the non-trivial elements of the  $V$ are precisely the permutations in $S_4$ whose cyclic structure is the product of two transpositions, so the claim immediately follows.

Comment: I know this. My question isn't why $V \unlhd S_4$. It is specifically about the argument in the highlighted text.

Comment: I have explained this. If you take the conjugate of a non-trivial element $g$ in $V$ you remain inside $V$, since $V$ contains *all* the elements with the same cyclic structure of $g$. The proof you present, although correct, is unnecessaryly involved (in my opinion, of course).

Comment: I don't care if it is unnecessarily involved, I want to understand it. I understand the proof you presented. I would like to understand what "symmetry" they are talking about.

Comment: Could you please explain how the argument is an application of this fact?

Comment: The "simmetry" is precisely the principle I have written in my answer. If a transposition $(i\, j)$ is in the conjugacy class of $V$, then *all* transposition must be in it, because all transpositions have the same cyclic structure and so they are all conjugate.

Comment: Okay, now I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have $s \in S_4, v\in V$ such that $svs^{-1} = (i\ j) \not\in V$. Then for any $a,b \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ we have:

$(a\ i)(b\ j)(svs^{-1})(a\ i)(b\ j) = (a\ i)(b\ j)(i\ j)(a\ i)(b\ j) = (a\ b)$ in the conjguacy class of $v$ as well, since this equals:

$tvt^{-1}$ with $t = (a\ i)(b\ j)s$.

(With the usual caveats if $\{a,b\} \cap \{i,j\} \neq \emptyset$, i'm sure you can figure out these cases on your own).

Comment: This is the direct resolution.

Comment: This is actually great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If one can obtain (12) by computing $sv s^{-1}$ one can also obtain (23), (34), ... because S4 and your V are symmetrical in that every possible permutation of a form is contained in them.

Elaboration: permutations of order 2 in $S_4$ must be products of disjoint 2-cycles and since we're in $S_4$ there are exactly two forms of them: $(ij)(kl)$ and $(ij)$. The former is exhausted in constructing V and so if a conjugate of $v \in V$ is not in $V$ it must be of the latter form. This actually cannot be done, and the proof relies on that for a reductio ad absurdum reasoning.

Comment: This really doesn't explain much. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Gee, I am pretty sure I asked about a very specific thing in my question. I understand all of the argument except the "symmetry" part.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the actual question asked by the OP.